# Apply search and filter in power Apps

Tags: powerapps

[image: Here I am getting the searching results. But I want to Apply filter on Searching Results.]

Here I am getting the searching results. But I want to Apply filter on Searching Results.

I have a another column name `Sale Order Created`. I want to show results only if this column value is 0.

How to achieve this?

I am new to power Apps. This is my First Application.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerApps most functions that operate on tables (such as [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup), [SortByColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-sort) and [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup)) return the searches / sorted / filtered table, so you can compose them together, by applying one function to the result of the other. For example, in your case, you can [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) the result of the [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup), by using the latter's result as the first parameter of the former, as shown below.

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Search(
            '[dbo].[Efftronics Systems Pbt Ltd_,$Sales Header]',
            TextSearchBox1.Text,
            "No_"),
        'Sale Order Created' = 0),
    "No_",
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Filter**

```
Search(Filter('[dbo]...', column_name = 0),...
```